# load d3.js and c3.js from directory dosen't work

Tags: node.js, d3.js, c3.js

i will creat some charts on my website. 
I start a server with node.js and include d3 and c3 with the links:

```js
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.js"></script>
```

This works creat on my Site and i can see the example chart from the c3 page.
But i will not load this from the web, so i downloaded d3.js and c3.js.

My new tags are:

```js
<script src="/load_moduls/c3/c3.js"></script>
<script src="/load_moduls/d3/d3.js"></script>
```

The html - page is in the directory "Client". In this folder is another folder "load_moduls" which include the c3 and d3 folder.

But that dosen't work. 
Here is my error from chrome:

GET http://localhost:3000/load_moduls/d3/d3.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Is this because of node.js? howi can fix it?

nice evening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tags are `<script src="/load_moduls/d3/d3.js"></script>`

but your request is http://localhost:3000/load_moduls/d3/d3.min.js
check your typo first.
if it is correctly, did you serve static file ?

Comment: Hi and Thanks. i thought i'd have to specify the folder i'm sharing via static in the url. But now i know how to handle it ;)